# Multiple integrals and uniform continuity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, uniform-continuity, multiple-integral

> For a function $$f (x,y)$$ continuous on $[a,b]\times J$, where $J$ is an open interval:
>
> $$g(y) = \int_a^b\ f(x,y)\  \mathrm dx$$ is also continuous.

My question is: if $J$ is a closed then $f$ is uniformly continuous, does this new quality also apply for the function $g$?

Comment: Do you want it to say $\int_a^bf(x,y)\mathrm{dx}$?  Also, shouldn't this be $g(y)$ not $g(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $f$ uniformly continuous on $[a,b] \times J$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta(\epsilon) > 0$ such that for all $x \in [a,b]$ and for all $y_1,y_2 \in J$ with $|y_1 - y_2| < \delta(\epsilon)$ we have

$$|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)| < \epsilon/(b-a)$$

Notice that $\delta(\epsilon)$ does not depend upon $x$,$y_1$ and $y_2.$

Using,

$$|g(y_1) - g(y_2)| \leqslant \int_a^b |f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)| \, dx,$$

you should now be able to answer the question.

Comment: then we get: $$|g(y_1) - g(y_2)| \leqslant \epsilon$$ which proves continuity but does it prove uniform continuity?

Comment: and in the expression $$|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)| < \epsilon/(b-a)$$ is the $\epsilon/(b-a)$ chosen arbitrarly?

Comment: Yes -- you have proved uniform continuity because $|g(y_1)-g(y_2)|< \epsilon$ when $|y_1-y_2| < \delta(\epsilon)$, where $\delta(\epsilon)$ does not depend on $y_1$ and $y_2$ when they are in the interval $J$.  I chose $\epsilon/(b-a)$ for the bound on $|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)|$ for convenience so that $\epsilon$ would appear in the final expression.

Comment: By uniform continuity of $f$ we can make $|f(x,y_1) - f(x, y_2)|$ smaller than anything we want by taking $y_1$ and $y_2$ sufficiently close -- independent of the individual values $y_1$ and $y_2$ as long as $|y_1-y_2|$ is small.